# How to set a unique constraint using Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to do the following:

**In the Application Class:
Add a UNIQUE constraint named IX_Unique_Applicatation as a business rule to
make sure that no one can apply to the same posting more than once.**

I'm trying to apply this to

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace solution_MVC_HR.Models
{
    public class Application
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Covering Comments")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You cannot leave the summary comments blank.")]
        [StringLength(2000,ErrorMessage ="Summary must be between 20 and 2000 characters",MinimumLength =20)]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Comments { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="You must specify the job posting applied for.")]
        public int PostingID { get; set; }

        public virtual Posting Posting { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must specify the applicant applying to the job posting.")]
        public int ApplicantID { get; set; }

        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }

    }
}
```

When I Add-Migration IX_Unique_Applicatation I get:

```
public partial class IX_Unique_Applicatation : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
```

It's completely blank (obviously should have stuff in the void up and void Down I've tried it on a couple different fields..I don't see where I'm going wrong and would greatly appreciate the help.

edit: I've attempted this kind of coding with it giving me an error about my Unique on the ID field?

```
[Index("IX_MyTwoColumns", 1, IsUnique = true)]
public int UserAttributeId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserAttributeId")]
public virtual UserAttribute UserAttribute { get; set; }
```

Comment: When this happens, I copy by Configuration.cs file somewhere (if anything is in it), then I:
1. Delete the Migrations folder
2. Re-enable migrations using the 'enable-migrations' command.
3. You should now be able to re-run 'add-migration *' and see your changes in those methods.

Comment: @IanGesner My Migrations work, as I can do a different Unique on another table but it isn't on a Virtual like this one is.

Comment: "to make sure that no one can apply to the same posting more than once" -- what is a posting? There can only be one applicant per application, so do you need this FK to be unique? If so, any applicant can only apply once *ever*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know doing this with data annotations, but you can try this.

In your DbContext class:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
 {
       builder.Entity<Application>()
            .HasIndex(a => a.Applicant)
            .IsUnique();
 }
```